# iOS :: Navigation bar does not appear

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am developing an iOS app and using web view to show some html data in it.
i have added navigation bar in it. navigation bar used to show before.
 But when i added below code,it stopped showing it.

```
// the base view for this view controller
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// important for view orientation rotation
contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
contentView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
self.view = contentView;
[contentView release];

//Initialize the WebView -----------------------------------------------------------
CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
   // webFrame.origin.y += kTopMargin + 5.0;    // leave from the URL input field and its label
//webFrame.origin.y -= 20.0;
myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
//myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
myWebView.detectsPhoneNumbers = NO;
//myWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
myWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
myWebView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview: myWebView];
```

any help will be appreciated....

Answer (score 4):

write this code in viewDidLoad of controller.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

Your code perfectly working on my  project.

Comment: what is your RootViewController of window in appDelegate class? UINavigationController or ViewController.

Comment: can you show here your code of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: is it possible to have some issue with xib?